# FULLCALENDAR - trazer eventos

Tags: fullcalendar, dinâmico

Temos na configuração do Fullcalendar a parte de trazer os eventos em forma de json, eu sigo o seguinte modelo:

```
$('#full-calendar').fullCalendar({
  events:{
          url: 'php_ajax/jq_agenda_calendario_dados.php',
          cache: true,      
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
                 param1: '',
                 param2: ''
                }
        }
});
```

Existe alguma maneira de passar parametros na `url` ou na `data` , pois do jeito que estou fazendo eu tenho que trazer toda a base de dados com os eventos. Eu gostaria de acordo com que a pessoa vai avançando ou retrocendo no calendário, passar um parametro para trazer somente aquele período em que a pessoa esta visualizando o calendario.

Comment: Atualmente você já tá passando 2 parâmetros varias, são eles: **param1** e **param2**. Você também pode passar como get na própria url: ```php_ajax/jq_agenda_calendario_dados.php?param1=valorQualquer&param2=outroValor```.

Comment: Eu ja tentei fazer isso, mas eu não consigo passar valores para essas variávies, não estou conseguindo trazer nenhum dado para ser colocado nelas, veja eu criei um pasterbin com o codigo
https://pastebin.com/WCC9sXhd
Na linha 143 e que entra os events, mas não estou conseguindo passar os parametros.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, neste trecho do código ```url: 'php_ajax/jq_movi_pessoas.php?acao=e&foto='+foto,``` você está passando 2 parâmetros via get, ou seja, no script PHP gastaria capturar mais ou menos assim: ```$_GET['acao']``` e ```$_GET['foto']```

Comment: Isso foi um teste que fiz, esse trecho é acionado pelo botão adicionar eventos, que eu coloquei no fullcalendar.
Veja lá na linha 143 é que traz os dados dos eventos, veja, que a query que eu executo traz todos os eventos, sem nenhum filtro porque eu não consigo passar nenhum parametro para fazer um filtro na query.
É isso que eu estou querendo tentar entender.
Você por acaso consegue filtrar os eventos por exemplo, de acordo com o mês/ano que esta sendo exibido pelo fullcalendar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

                var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                    locale: 'pt-br',
                    plugins: ['dayGrid'],
                    defaultView: 'dayGridWeek',
                    events: {
                        url: 'url.php',
                        method: 'POST',
                        extraParams: {param1: 'param1', param2: $('#param2').val()},
                        failure: function () {
                            console.log('erro');

                        }
                    },
                    loading: function (bool) {
                        console.log('vai carregar'); 
                    }
                });

                calendar.render();
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenta isso:

```
eventClick: function(event) {

                            $('#visualizar #id').text(event.id);
                            $('#visualizar #id').val(event.id);
                            $('#visualizar #title').text(event.title);
                            $('#visualizar #title').val(event.title);
                            $('#visualizar #start').text(event.start.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
                            $('#visualizar #start').val(event.start.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
                            $('#visualizar #end').text(event.end.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
                            $('#visualizar #end').val(event.end.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
                            $('#visualizar #color').val(event.color);
                            $('#visualizar').modal('show');
                            return false;

                        },
```

Se quiser da uma olhada nesse fullcalendar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUlk2rMkKyc

Comment: Não entendi sua resposta em relação a pergunta. Poderia [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/296857/edit) sua resposta e detalhar melhor a solução proposta.

Comment: Opa Andre Lira, vou verificar isso e retorno obrigado